# Extending the page in Django

Tags: django, django-cms

Hi everyone I create my first page extension in Django-cms I save the info buy I can obtain it again

my model is like this

```
class PageDescriptionExtension(PageExtension):
    description_page = models.TextField('description',
      default = None,
      help_text = 'Please provide a small description about this page',
      max_length = 250,
      )
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='icons')

extension_pool.register(PageDescriptionExtension)
```

my `admin.py` is this

```
class PageDescriptionExtensionAdmin(PageExtensionAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(PageDescriptionExtension, PageDescriptionExtensionAdmin)
```

and my toolbar

```
class PageDescriptionExtensionToolbar(ExtensionToolbar):
    # defines the model for the current toolbar
    model = PageDescriptionExtension

    def populate(self):
        # setup the extension toolbar with permissions and sanity checks
        current_page_menu = self._setup_extension_toolbar()
        # if it's all ok
        if current_page_menu:
            # retrieves the instance of the current extension (if any) and the toolbar item URL
            page_extension, url = self.get_page_extension_admin()
            if url:
                # adds a toolbar item
                current_page_menu.add_modal_item(_('Description page'), url=url,
                    disabled=not self.toolbar.edit_mode)
```

no in my template when I try to bet the element

```
{% if request.current_page.pagedescriptionextension %}
  <img src="{% static request.current_page.pagedescriptionextension.image.url %}">
{% else %}
  here
{% endif %}
```

this code print `here` I do this in home page `request.current_page` return home but `request.current_page.pagedescriptionextension` don't return anything, any idea about that.

Thank in advance

Comment: From a first glance it looks like it should work - is the toolbar working?

Comment: hi @petr, yes toolbar works!

Comment: .. and have you tried if it saves the data properly etc? Are you seeing the same behaviour on all pages? Also, is the page you are looking at fully published?

Comment: Hi @petr I think that I found the problem, I have a submenu  that I call in the home page, like this `{% show_menu 2 100 100 100 "partials/menu_image.html" %}` I set the image in each page of this submenu, but I show this menu in home page so `request.current_page` is home page,  this page no has image so don't show anything, if I set a image to home page I see the same image in all of submenu page, How to get the image that I set in each page of submenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the page extension in the menus (for example, to enable page icons shown in the menu), you first need to add the icon information to the [navigation node](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/menus.html). In the snippet below, I am adding ability to fetch `pagemenuiconextension`, which is defined very similarly to your page extension. The menu extension needs to be placed in `cms_menus.py`:

```
from menus.base import Modifier
from menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
from raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.models import client

from cms.models import Page

class MenuModifier(Modifier):
    """
    Injects page object into menus to be able to access page icons
    """
    def modify(self, request, nodes, namespace, root_id, post_cut, breadcrumb):
        # if the menu is not yet cut, don't do anything
        if post_cut:
            return nodes

        for node in nodes:

            try: 
                if "is_page" in node.attr and node.attr["is_page"]:

                    class LazyPage(object):
                        id = node.id
                        page = None
                        def pagemenuiconextension(self):
                            try:
                                if not self.page:
                                    self.page = Page.objects.get(id=self.id)
                                return self.page.pagemenuiconextension
                            except AttributeError, ae:
                                # print ae
                                return False
                            except Exception, e:
                                print e
                                client.captureException()

                    node.pageobj = LazyPage()

                else:
                    pass
            except Exception, e:
                client.captureException()

        return nodes

menu_pool.register_modifier(MenuModifier)
```

Then you can access it in the menu file (snippet from the corresponding menu item):

```
<div class="{{ child.pageobj.pagemenuiconextension.menu_navicon }}" style="height: 16px;">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</div>
```

The page extension looks something like this:

```
class PageMenuIconExtension(PageExtension):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("menu and robots settings")
        verbose_name_plural = _("menu and robots settings")

    menu_navicon = models.CharField(
        _("Page icon"),
        choices=MENU_ICON_CHOICES,
        blank=True,
        max_length=50        
    )
```

In my case I am using a dropdown to select a class, not an image itself but the principle is the same if you used any other data.